# Keyboard stopped working after upgrading to Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, hp, 18.04

After upgrading to Kubuntu 18.04 from 17.10 my built-in keyboard on HP Envy 15 stopped working in Plasma only. Touchpad works, external usb keyboard works. 
Please kindly help

Answer (score 0):

the software/package Kubuntu 17.10 used for that keyboard, can be deleted during the upgrade.
that can happen in the proces were all deemed´unnessesary´ packages are deleted and replaced by the new/updated ones from the new OS version.

the only tip i can give you, is to look at ´additional drivers´ in 18.04.
there might be software showed for the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to bother and installed a new copy alongside upgraded. Fresh install doesn't have any issues so I guess some packages got corrupted during the upgrade.